# how to avoid table-layout avoid for certain elements of the table?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

So i've been trying to use table-layout fixed so that the content get's it's width by the largest one but i don't want that to happen to all of the data's. Some of them need to have a width by the content itself not by a sibling they have in the same row. Here's the code

```
 <table>
    <tbody>
     <tr>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
        <th>2012</th>
        <th>2011</th>
        <th>Var</th>
     </tr>
     <tr>
        <td class="day">M</td>
        <td class="date">3</td>
        <td>300,500</td>
        <td>300,500</td>
        <td>0%</td>
     </tr>
     <tr>
        <td class="day">T</td>
        <td class="date">4</td>
        <td>300,500</td>    
        <td>300,500</td>
        <td>0%</td>
     </tr>
  </tbody>
```

And here's the CSS

```
table {
    float: left;
    width: 100%;
    height: auto;
    margin-top: 20px;
    table-layout: fixed;
    display: table;
    }
table tr{
   border-bottom: 1px solid #ccc;
   width: 100%;
}
table tr th{
    text-align: center;
}
table tr td{
    display: table-cell;
    text-align: center;        
}
```

So the question is that i want the td's with class date and day to have width by their own width like width = auto to avoid the table cell function. What do you guy's suggest i should do. Can i do this in CSS or shall i do a script for that.

Comment: Do you mean you want every day and date cell to have a width on their own, so the table won't be aligned well?

Comment: I think is better defining it on css. You should define a with for the date and day classes

Comment: @rednaw yeah that's what i wan't to do and Kedume that didn't worked as i tried too but the inherited code on the parent didn't let it bee optimized and it always kept adding padding and margin to keep that width.

Comment: Try display: inline-block; for the date/day td's